# Disable printing

Tags: printer

I installed Elementary OS on an old PC for a disabled adult. First I really love the ability to disable all the apps except the one you need. This person will push every button and try every feature. They also love to print pictures with no regard to ink usage. If left unchecked they would print through an entire ream of paper in no time. I went in to the terminal and disabled CUPS completely. The print button is ghosted out. But if you double click on the printer it will print the job. Is there a way to completely disable all print services?